# FDA Cosmetics Data

Tags: data-request, openfda

I see that open.fda.gov has data for drugs, food, etc, but I can't find anything about cosmetics (makeup, shampoo etc) recalls. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, openFDA does not provide any datasets related to cosmetics.

Comment: I've been coming to the same conclusion, but that seems crazy. Have you reviewed iRES and OpenFDA? To be fair, I can't find it in ires either!

Answer (score 1):

Foods, dietary supplements, and cosmetics are categorized as food and included in the food API endpoints available on OpenFDA (recalls and adverse events).